# Using Unisim with GHDL: vital_timing and vital_primitives not found in ieee library

Tags: ghdl

I'm trying to simulate a component that uses a component from the Xilinx Unisim library that came with ISE.  How can I do that?

Here is what I tried.  I ran into a problem I don't understand.

```
$ ls
DualPortMemory.vhd  TestDualPortMemory.vhd  Utilities.vhd
$ ghdl --clean
$ ghdl -i --work=unisim /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/*.vhd
$ ghdl -i --work=unisim /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/primitive/*.vhd
$ ghdl -i *.vhd
$ ghdl -m -g -Punisim --warn-unused --ieee=synopsys TestDualPortMemory
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/primitive/RAMB16_S9_S18.vhd:24:10:error: unit "vital_timing" not found in library "ieee"
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/unisim_VPKG.vhd:48:10:error: unit "vital_timing" not found in library "ieee"
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/unisim_VPKG.vhd:49:10:error: unit "vital_primitives" not found in library "ieee"
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/unisim_VPKG.vhd:66:16:error: no declaration for "vitaltablesymboltype"
/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/vhdl/src/unisims/unisim_VPKG.vhd:67:16:error: no declaration for "vitaltablesymboltype"
```

And then many many more errors.

Here is the GHDL version information:

```
GHDL 0.37 (Ubuntu 0.37+dfsg-1ubuntu1) [Dunoon edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: 9.3.0
 llvm code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2020 Tristan Gingold.
GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: ghdl 2.0 was released last week. There have been several thousand deficiencies corrected or features added since 0.37. Consider upgrading. VITAL is used for timed model simulation (usually post synthesis). Unless some open source license zealotry by a distributor prevents it (there's a make target for that) the vital2000 packages (post -1987) are found in ghdl's library tree (usually /usr/local/lib/ghdl/src/vital2000.  The VITAL packages can be analyzed into library IEEE.

Comment: One of ghdl's [nightly builds](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases), e.g. [ghdl-gha-ubuntu-20.04-llvm.tgz](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases/download/nightly/ghdl-gha-ubuntu-20.04-llvm.tgz) would have the VITAL libraries installed in library IEEE but would need a compatible llvm install (libLLVM.so, the big dynamic library is used,  I use a Mac and don't have a tools to interrogate the version of llvm used, from strings and grep it looks like an llvm-10.0.0. You can download and ldd (ghdl1-llvm). Likely the same as used by your 0.37.

Comment: using objdump -p | grep NEED (thanks Linux man page for ldd) on the above archive's bin/ghdl1-llvm gives [llvm10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv0wk.jpg). I was surprised to see all the dynamic library dependencies, there's only 3 in the MacOS versions, and two of those are from the system.

Comment: You can also install the archived ghdl anywhere as long as you keep the bin, include, and lib locations relational.  You can specify which ghdl with an alias or by order in the search path without disturbing the present installation. The dylib search path would relate to the default install location (/usr/local) and you probably wouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: I think the problem was that I didn't specify to use `--std=93`!

Comment: Is there a binary version of 2.0 for Linux or do we need to build from source?

Comment: The default ghdl standard version is --std=93c which has some relaxed rules to match commercial simulators, --std=93 would be strict standard compliance. Major releases are available only as source. Nightly releases are incremental from the last release and represent builds used to verify changes. Ubuntu uses there own versioning scheme, while ghdl nightly binaries show where and when they are from: `GHDL 3.0.0-dev (2.0.0.r26.g7ee7edde) [Dunoon edition]`. It's the 26th change to the source tree since the 2.0 release. 7ee7edde uniquely identifies the github commit to the Master branch.

Comment: @user16145658 Thanks. The problem with 93c is that we get all those errors shown above.  Our code is almost 93 compliant and I don't think it's much work to get it to where it all complies.  So switching from 93c to 93 seems to solve this problem. But upgrading to 2.0 or 3.0 might fix some other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Vital package doesn't seem to be present in GHDL binary but it is there in source. you can check in /lib/ghdl/gcc/vhdl/ieee/v93 for .o files and /lib/ghdl/gcc/vhdl/src/ieee/v93 for .vhd sources.
if sources are not present then download them from:
https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/tree/master/libraries/vital95
and compile using "sudo ghdl -a --workdir=/lib/ghdl/gcc/vhdl/ieee/v93 --work=ieee vital_timing.vhd vital_timing-body.vhd vital_primitives.vhd vital_primitives-body.vhd" in order shown. where workdir represents path to wherever compiled packages are saved.
I don't know if it will help the simulation but unisim compiled for me.